# Terraform multiple commands at once

Tags: docker, docker-compose, terraform

Хочу запустить terraform в compose файле, чтобы он сразу апплаил все скрипты что будут лежать в папке, но для начала его нужно проинициализировать командой init , а потом только apply. Но compose файл запускает лишь одну команду за раз, или терраформ принимает лишь одну команду за раз - не знаю((

Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

Вот мой пример:

```
version: '3.9'

services:

  terraform:
    image: hashicorp/terraform:latest
    container_name: terraform
    volumes:
      - ./scripts:/scripts
    command: >
      apply /terraform-init-scripts -auto-approve
#      init //need to run it first and comment the apply command and recompose it second time with apply command and comment this one
```

Comment: а зачем вам terraform в docker compose? это же не полноценный сервис, а просто обертка над cli, terraform хранит состояние в файлах (или облачных хранилищах), когда вы их будете монтировать вам не нужно будет выполнять init/plan/apply каждый раз, т.к. состояние будет общее между запусками контейнеров

Comment: @Exploding это только кусочек compose файла, очевидно есть и другие сервисы

Comment: а если объединить 2 в одну `init && apply /terraform-init-scripts -auto-approve`? Если не выйдет, то надо создать свой скрипт запуска, положить его в подмонтированный `/scripts`  и запускать уже его.

Comment: сделайте `*.sh` файл в котором вызывайте нужные вам команды.